# I see 5 different profiles on my NixOS system; which is which?

Tags: nixos

I have a NixOS installation with one user (`my-username` below) other than root, and I'm trying to understand how to clean up and roll back different aspects of my system.

Digging around in `/nix/var/nix/profiles`, I can see at least 5 distinct-looking profiles, and I want to be clear on what I'm cleaning up/rolling back when I target each of them:

```
❯❯❯ nix-env --list-generations --profile /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/my-username/channels
   7   2020-01-11 14:53:26   (current)
❯❯❯ nix-env --list-generations --profile /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/my-username/profile
  61   2020-01-22 19:53:12
  62   2020-01-26 13:43:10
  63   2020-01-26 16:19:39
  64   2020-01-26 16:22:40
  65   2020-01-26 16:45:32
  66   2020-01-26 17:20:41   (current)
❯❯❯ sudo nix-env --list-generations --profile /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels
   7   2019-12-09 11:31:07   (current)
❯❯❯ sudo nix-env --list-generations --profile /nix/var/nix/profiles/default
   2   2019-10-18 23:19:20   (current)
❯❯❯ sudo nix-env --list-generations --profile /nix/var/nix/profiles/system
 108   2020-01-26 16:27:21
 109   2020-01-26 16:31:29
 110   2020-01-26 16:35:58
 111   2020-01-26 16:51:56
 112   2020-01-26 17:10:54
 113   2020-01-26 17:19:06
 114   2020-01-26 17:27:45   (current)
```

Here's my understanding of each of these:

1. Channels (references to a collection of versioned packages) my non-root account can install from.
2. A set of versioned packages my non-root user has installed.
3. Channels my root account can install from.
4. A set of versioned packages my root user has installed.
5. System configurations (managed by root).

Is my understanding of each of these correct, and if not, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Similarly, there's also `nix-collect-garbage`, which I think deletes stale packages on my system not referenced by any of the above profies?